# Eclipse's tips on F2 hotkey won't work with installed Spring Tools4

Tags: spring-tools-4

I have installed Spring Tools 4 in Eclipse and with the plugin expected behavior by F2 won't work.

When I uninstall Spring Tools the functionality comes back. After install Spring Tools - disappeared again.

I saw hotkeys, nothing is changed for F2 key.

Is it a bug of Spring Tools or I have to change something in eclipse by myself?

---

UPD.1:

I have next installed:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers.
Version: 2020-03 (4.15.0)
Build id: 20200313-1211

Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tool Suite 4) 4.7.0.RELEASE
```

I write somewhere in code `doIt()` to create new method (for example) and press F2 to see "quick fixes". **Nothing happened** if Spring Tools is installed. By Ctrl+1 Eclipse shows available actions:

[image]

When I uninstall Spring Tools then F2 works again:

[image]

---

UPD.2:

Two days ago Eclipse ask me to update himself and plugins. After apply this update (with some Spring Tools components too) F2 works again.

For now I have:

```
Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)
Build id: 20200615-1200

Spring Tools 4 (aka Spring Tool Suite 4) 4.7.0.RELEASE
```

Comment: I am running Spring Tools for Eclipse 4.7.0 on top of Eclipse 2020-06 and `F2` seems to do its job (e.g. on my macOS machine: invoking the rename dialog for selected elements in the package explorer or show the tooltip description in the java editor for the cursor position). What do you expect and what happens in your case? And which version so you have installed?

Comment: @MartinLippert, I have updated the question provided screenshots. But after upgrade eclipse it seems that F2 is worked.

Comment: still puzzled why it doesn't work on 2020-03, but glad to hear that it works now after updating to 2020-06.